# Python регулярное выражение для поиска свойств класса

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, строки

Считываю файлы в папке в которых находятся классы. С классов нужно достать поля.
(в классах может быть такой стиль писания полей, в этом сложность.)

```
class Son(Father):

    def __init__(self
                 , first
                 , second
                 , third                 
                 ):
        super().__init__(self
                       , first
                       , second                       
                       )
```

Для обычного кода где поля не столбиком а в ряд применил такое

```
result = re.findall(r'self,.*', x) # x = считаный файл
```

но вот с столбиками я не знаю как достать значения.

Нужно достать только поля класса наследника.

Comment: [ошибка молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/178576)?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Извините а что именно в вопросе нужно поправить?

Comment: @Александр объясните для чего вы используете это "считывание", возможно, есть варианты сделать это куда эффективнее

Comment: А что ищет ноль у вас в шаблоне? Я что-то не очень понимаю

Comment: @CrazyElf В некоторых классах где обычное написание полей работал как заглушка(по причине что в некоторых классах есть допустим поле fourth=0 , не могу пока понять регулярные-выражения. Получается так если с 0 то выводило дочерний класс, а без вместе с родительским. (пока писал понял как поправить эту глупость сейчас поправлю в вопросе, и уберу 0).

Comment: @n1tr0xs Понял, в следующий раз буду описывать более подробно. На данном этапе ответ удовлетворителен. Спасибо за участие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понимаю, что именно вы ищете, но вроде всё ищется довольно тривиальными шаблонами:

```
import re

x = '''
class Son(Father):

    def __init__(self
                 , first
                 , second
                 , third                 
                 ):
        super().__init__(self
                       , first
                       , second                       
                       )
'''

result = re.findall(r'self\s*,[^)]*', x) # x = считаный файл
result = [re.sub(r'\s+', '', r) for r in result]
print(result)
```

Вывод:

```
['self,first,second,third', 'self,first,second']
```

Здесь я просто ищу символы, идущие до закрывающей скобки. Ну и потом ещё лишние пробелы убираю, их многовато получается.

Comment: Спасибо работает! А в квадратных скобках выражения, можете объяснить что происходит пожалуйста.

Comment: @Александр В квадратных скобках перечисляются символы, которые нужно искать, но если перед ними стоит `^`, то значит наоборот - это любые символы, кроме указанных. То есть под шаблон `[^)]` подходят любые символы кроме закрывающей скобки `)`.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо!